# Is it possible to bcc/cc an admin on every system email?

Tags: emails, admin

My understanding is that the `testToEmailAddress` config items *replaces* the **to** address for system emails.

Is there a way, outside of extending the system functionality with a plugin, to *add* a **to**/**cc**/**bcc** address for system emails? (Use case: I want to CC/BCC an admin on every system email.)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do that without any plugin by using a transactional email provider like https://mandrill.com/ or http://sendgrid.com/

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in Craft out of the box will allow you do to that.

You'd need to write a plugin that creates and populates an [EmailModel](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/models/EmailModel.php) with the settings you want and then pass that off to [EmailService->sendEmail()](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/services/EmailService.php#L67).